# Minimum number of knight moves to move from source to destination in a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

My goal is to to move from `source` to `destination` using the shortest number of steps in a matrix, by only making knight moves (L shaped moves)

Does a Depth-First search based solution work for this case? I'm apprehensive about the way I am handling already visited nodes. Please let me know if this is a valid solution.

```
public class knightminmoves {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int degree = 5;
        int[][] board = new int[degree][degree];
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[degree][degree];

        System.out.println( minMoves( 0, 0, degree - 1, degree - 1, board, visited ) );
    }


    static int minMoves( int x, int y, int destx, int desty, int[][] board, boolean[][] visited ) {
        if ( x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= board.length || y >= board[0].length )
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2;

        if ( x == destx && y == desty )
            return 0;

        if ( visited[x][y] == true )
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2;
        else
            visited[x][y] = true;

        int upleft = minMoves( x - 2, y - 1, destx, desty, board, visited );
        int upright = minMoves( x - 2, y + 1, destx, desty, board, visited );
        int downleft = minMoves( x + 2, y - 1, destx, desty, board, visited );
        int downright = minMoves( x + 2, y + 1, destx, desty, board, visited );
        int leftup = minMoves( x - 1, y - 2, destx, desty, board, visited );
        int leftdown = minMoves( x + 1, y - 2, destx, desty, board, visited );
        int rightup = minMoves( x - 1, y + 2, destx, desty, board, visited );
        int rightdown = minMoves( x + 1, y + 2, destx, desty, board, visited );

        visited[x][y] = false;

        return min( upleft, upright, downleft, downright, leftup, leftdown, rightup, rightdown ) + 1;
    }

    static int min( int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h ) {
        int[] arr = new int[8];
        arr[0] = a;
        arr[1] = b;
        arr[2] = c;
        arr[3] = d;
        arr[4] = e;
        arr[5] = f;
        arr[6] = g;
        arr[7] = h;

        Arrays.sort( arr );
        return arr[0];
    }

}
```

Comment: If this code is working, I believe this should be asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Without even looking at your code, one conceptual thing: for the *shortest* path, you should not use depth-first (which eventually traces every possible path to maximum length befor trying the next) but breadth-first.

Comment: Read about [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm). Can you conceptualize your problem as a graph?

Comment: @mtj thanks for the reply? So DFS should not be used when there are cycles in graph?

Comment: It's not a matter of cycles. DFS should not be used because it will find the first *valid* path, not the *minimal* path.

Comment: @learningboy What RealSkeptic said. If you want to find the minimal path via DFS, you'd have to determine *all* paths first, then compare their length to find the minimal one. If you use BFS, the first valid solution will be one of the minimal set by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but it is slow. It is not depth-first search. As it marks a visited node as unvisited, your program just generates all simple paths and picks the shortest one. It is an exhaustive search. It has an exponential time complexity, so it would take too long to complete on larger boards. You can use breadth-first search to get an efficient and correct solution that scales well.

Comment: someone told me that my solution is incorrect since, say we, start from (0,0) and go to (1,2). At (1,2), a possible path is also to (0,0). But we don't know the value of (0,0) since it's calculation is still unfinished since it's waiting on the calculation of (1,2). So, since (0,0) and (1,2) are dependent on each other, this is not a candidate for Dynamic Programming. Is this true? On similar lines, he told me that this problem is also, not possible to solve by depth first search/recursion - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/snake-ladder-problem-2/

Comment: The way I look at it, if you have gone to (1,2) from (0,0), then, at (1,2), there is no need to consider going back to (0,0) as one of the possible options, since it anyways cannot be the shortest path, since you're at the same position as you were previously, just that you made an extra couple of moves.

Comment: @learningboy Depth first search doesn't work here. A recursive solution that checks all simple paths (yes, it is never necessary to return to (0,0)) works, but it is exponential. As for dynamic programming, it depends on it's defenition. Some people consider Djikstra's algorithm and breadth first search to be dynamic programming. In this sense, a dynamic programming solution work.

Comment: thanks. Would be great if you could clarify that my understanding is correct. When you say DFS doesn't work, that's because, DFS only gives you local minima, whereas the recursive solution goes to all possible paths, and compares between possible paths ? I think my friend who said my solution does not work, was also intending to say that you cannot cache results like in DP any time, because the minimum hops for reaching any cell depends on the route you have taken, so it's not constant unlike in say, Fibonacci series where Fib(x) is constant and does not need recalculation?